# Android Views and Activities

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android Development and am a little confused over views and activities.

I have just created a new android project with a blank activity having the "Navigation Drawer" as the navigation type.

For example, as the app navigates between each item on the navigation pane, should a new activity be launched or should that be just a new view within the main activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Activity should contain Fragments, each Fragment should inflate Views.

You can take a look at this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

In your case, the navigation drawer should be in your activity. Each "screen" that you want to link with your navigation drawer should be in a Fragment.

Comment: So in the case of an app with a navigation drawer, am I right to say that the entire app can run in just one Activity, though it may have many different views?

Comment: You are correct, an application can be based on a sole activity. The activity could be seen as the master frame of the app. In this frame you will have one or multiple fragments (that I think you are calling views). The actual views in android are graphic layout elements. ie: a gridLayout is a view, a linearLayout is another view, ... And you can nest or stack these layouts in each other. See this article about layouts: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html